# Resizing text size in SDL2 C++ when a user changes display dimentions

Tags: c++, math, sdl-2

I am trying to make an application that is able to be resized, i.e., like Google Chrome, Word, etc., where you can make it smaller horizontally or vertically or maximise it completely.

For me to do this and allow everything to be in ratio, I need a formula of some sort to determine what scale is appropriate for text sizes. For rectangles, you can scale down the width as a ratio of the display width, and likewise for its height, but for text sizes, its different, you need a single integer value.

If anyone has any ideas how to do this, or even a completely different way that works for everything, it would be great.

Comment: ... Just scale text according to the window height? Preferably with a decent upper- and lower bound.

Comment: I like it how, in tkinter, regardless of how it is scaled it fits perfectly though

Comment: Perhaps you should investigate how tkinter does it, then. Presumably it tries to keep text size locked to both specific sizes in the font _and_ within a given range of the window height. So an algorithm could be: find the largest font size available that makes the text fit in the provided space in the window.